# How to achieve Expandable TextField with Center Align of text and prefixIcon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am stuck in trying to achieve a text field with prefix Icon. I want the text field and prefixIcon to be center-aligned and should expand while typing.
Any help, please
[image]

Comment: By expand do you mean the `width` of TextField of the `height` of textfield?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something you are looking for:

```dart
class HomeTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeTestState createState() => _HomeTestState();
}

class _HomeTestState extends State<HomeTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 250.0,
            child: TextField(
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0,
                  vertical: 12.0,
                ),
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                hintText: "Type Something...",
                // border: OutlineInputBorder()
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Adjustments

- Use `contentPadding` according to your need
- Change `fontSize` of the text if needed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code.But the prefix icon doesn't expand increase of text.
I have commented if someone could try please update it.

```
              Container(
                  height: somevalue..,
                  width: somevalue..,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  //color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: TextField(
                    cursorHeight: somevalue..,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    maxLength: 11,
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      counterText: "",
                    contentPadding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: -1),
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "\u20b90",
                       hintTextDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      // prefixIconConstraints:
                      //     BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 20, minWidth: 5),
                      // prefixIcon: Text(
                      //   "\u20b9",
                      //   style: TextStyle(
                      //       fontSize:
                      //           SizeUtils.horizontalBlockSize * 10),
                      // ),
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize:somevalue),
                  ),
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVtkc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty late to answer this question but I am answering because someone may find this helpful.

```
IntrinsicWidth(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: controller,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  maxLength: 11,
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
                       minWidth: 0, 
                       minHeight: 0),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Text('\$', style: TextStyle(color: ktextDarkBlack, fontSize: 32)),
                    counterText: "",
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: "0",
                    hintTextDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                  ),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: ktextDarkBlack,
                    fontSize: 35,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

In the above code, I used an `IntrinsicWidth()`. This will help to Size its child to maximum IntrinsicWidth. If this makes your `TextField` too small when it is empty you can use `ConstrainedBox()` to set the minWidth.